# Catalina MacOS on VMWare Expanding Storage

Tags: macos-catalina, vmware-workstation

I was trying to download XCode and it says it needs more space, I went and expand the storage and this message pop up

[image]

When I entered the VM, it still only have 40GB, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out what I should do, I had to run this line of command in the terminal in the VM.

`sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 60G`